# use readOGR to load in a large spatial file in R

Tags: r, split, large-data

For my processes in R I want to read in a 20 gigabyte file. I got it in a XML file type.

In R I cannot load it in with readOGR since it is to big. It gives me the error cannot allocate vector 99.8 mb.

Since my file is to big the logical next step in my mind would be to split the file. But since I can not open it in R and any other GIS package at hand, I can not split the file before I load it in. I am already using the best PC to my availability.

Is there a solution?

UPDATE BECAUSE OF COMMENT

If I use head() my line looks like underneath. It does not work unfortunately.

headfive <- head(readOGR('file.xml', layer = 'layername'),5)

Comment: If it's an XML file, it's human-readable. So I would say use the Unix commandline tools (`head`, `tail`, `vim` maybe) to cut half of the XML file and to reconstruct a proper valid XML tree adding the last lines of the original file at the bottom of your cut. That should do the job...

Comment: Try readLines(file, 10) to get an idea of what it actually is. GML?  20Gb is insane for XML, are you sure? Where and why and how did you get this? QGIS or GDAL directly can probably deal with it but it's pretty outrageous.

Comment: Yes I am sure the name of the file ends with .XML. Why is this outrageous? I am not a file type expert, but I am curious why XML is outrageous to use in large spatial files.

Comment: The extension is no guarantee of contents, and XML is text. Verbose text, so outrageous as in inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me. I have been googling and it apparently comes down to or use a different GIS package or to find a better computer. So I guess those are my options. I will leave the question open for someone who disagrees, I would be glad to find another option and work in R.

Comment: I agree with mdsumner. Can you please give us the output of a `head file.xml` command, and maybe also what is produced by a `tail file.xml`?

Comment: when I do head('file.xml') it just returns the name of the file. So file.xml, when I do tail('file.xml') it does the same.